# What is the length of the 4th side without draw rectangle?

Tags: geometry

I wish to know the length of the 4th side but without draw a rectangle. How to calculate it and what's the length of the 4th side?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Pythagorean theorem, the hypotenuse measures 41cm, the opposite cathetus measures (17cm-8cm)=9cm. Let x be the adjacent cathetus (the side you are looking for), you have:

(41cm)^{2} = (9cm)^{2}+x^{2}

x^{2}=1681 cm^{2} - 81 cm^{2}

x= sqrt(1600 cm^{2})

x= 40 cm